# Webpack favicons into different folder

Tags: webpack-3

I have two folders `src/images/` and `src/images/icons`.
All favicons are in `png` format.

In `src/images/icons` I put all the favicons for different devices, which I want to be webpacked to `wwwroot/images/icons` and all other images to `wwwroot/images`.

**How can I separate images and favicons?**

Now for images I have:

```
 {
            test: /\.(png|ico|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
            use: [
                'file-loader?name=/images/[name].[ext]'
            ]
        },
```

But this would copy all images to `dist\images`, including the icons, which should be one level deeper in folder `dist\images\icons`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this (i.e. use `test` key against filename, separate rules, etc). However, here is one way that seems to work well and is fairly clear:

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  // ...
  module: {
    rules: [

      {
        test: /\.(png|ico|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: function(fullPath) {
              return path.relative(__dirname + '/src', fullPath)
            }
          }
        }
      }

    ]
  }
  // ...
}
```

Comment: All the icons are in `png` format... that's the problem and I have other images in `png` format

Comment: @Legends how do you tell what is an icon and what isn't?

Comment: I have a `src/images/icons` folder where i have put all the icons and images are in `src/images`. In my markup I would use the respective url: `<link href="/dist/images/icons/xxx.png">`

Comment: I guess the `test:` checks against the resource path, perhaps if the regex could be modified to include the `icons` folder? Would that be a valid approach?

Comment: @Legends after playing around a bit, I found a way that seems to work well by preserving directory structure without needing too many regex acrobatics. Updated my answer accordingly

Comment: This works, great! One question, I get another `node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg` folder under `wwwroot` folder. How can I exclude this. With the old approach it wasn't there...

Comment: I've updated the answer: the standard way to do this is to put an `exclude: /node_modules/` key in the rule.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot  Joel!

Comment: There is one issue with this solution:
When using background-images in a css file, I get this:
`background: url(/dist/images\blue.jpg)`  --> the last slash is a backslash.
Now the image does not get resolved anymore.

Don't know, if there is a way to configure this, but now I replace all back-slashes with forward-slashes:

`return path.relative(rootfolder + '/src', fullPath).replace(/\\/g, '\/');`

Comment: @Legends that is strange... it could be a bug in the file loader plugin.